# Solving $\frac{dy}{dx} (x + y) x = y (x - y)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find the general solution to the second order differential equation $$ \frac{dy}{dx} (x + y) x = y (x - y)$$ I tried to rewrite this in the form of the Bernoulli's equation, which has the form $$ \frac{dy}{dx} + P(x) y(x) = Q(x) y^n (x) $$ but then I see this can't be done. Should I look for a substitution of some kind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice, $$\frac{dy}{dx}(x+y)x=y(x-y)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y(x-y)}{x(x+y)}=\frac{y}{x}\frac{\left(1-\frac{y}{x}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{y}{x}\right)}$$
Now, let $y=vx\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$ $$v+x\frac{dv}{dx}=v\frac{1-v}{1+v}$$
$$x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{-2v^2}{1+v}$$
$$\frac{(1+v)dv}{v^2}=-2\frac{dx}{x}$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{v^2}+\frac{1}{v}\right)dv=-2\frac{dx}{x}$$
I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks. I just began the study of differential equations. In my textbook it says:  when $y' (x) = f(x,y)$ with $f$ a homogenous function, i.e. $f(cx, cy) = f(x,y)$, then use the substitution $v = y/x$. I guess that is what you did here. But how do I know when to use this substitution? What do they mean with a homogenous function? Can you point that out in this example please?

Comment: Alright, you should use this method of substitution $y=vx$ or $\frac{y}{x}=v$ if you have the following form of D.E. $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{f(x, y)}{g(x, y)}=h\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Due to homogeneity of degree consider substitution  $ y = v x $ in

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac {x (x + y)  } { y (x - y)} $$

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a substitution in this case and change the variables in order to transform the equation into a variable separable one. Firstly, transform the equation by dividing both numerator and denominator of RHS by $x$ as follows:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y(x-y)}{x(x+y)}= \frac{y}{x} \frac{\frac{x}{x}-\frac{y}{x}}{\frac{x}{x}-\frac{y}{x}}= \frac{y}{x} \frac{1-\frac{y}{x}}{1-\frac{y}{x}}$$

Now let $t = \frac{y}{x}$

it follows that $\frac{dt}{dx} = -\frac{y}{x^2}+ \frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}$, $\implies \ x\frac{dt}{dx} + t =\frac{dy}{dx} $

The differential equation now becomes:

$$x\frac{dt}{dx} + t = \frac{t(1-t)}{1+t}$$

You can now solve this using separation of variables:

$$ \left( \frac{1}{t^2} + \frac{1}{t}\right)dt = -2\frac{1}{x} dx$$

You can solve this by integrating both sides and then re-substituting $t$ with $\frac{y}{x}$